# Prevent hyperlink Click event from bubbling up

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone, routed-events

I'm designing a windows Phone app. I have a `Hyperlink` object in a `RichTextBox`, in a `Grid`. The `Grid` had a `Tap` event, and the `Hyperlink` has a `Click` event.

**Clicking the `Hyperlink` also raises the parent `Grid`'s Tap event. How can I prevent this?**

I would use `e.Handled` in the `Click` handler, but `RoutedEventArgs` do not have a Handled property in Silverlight for Windows Phone... I also tried walking the logical tree to look for the original source, but the click appears to originate from a `MS.Internal.RichTextBoxView` control (`e.OriginalSource`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any good way from within the `Click` handler itself. The following state management can work though:

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Tap="ContentPanel_Tap_1">
    <RichTextBox Tap="RichTextBox_Tap_1">
       <Paragraph>
           fdsfdfdf
           <Hyperlink Click="Hyperlink_Click_1">fdsfdsfsaf</Hyperlink>
           fsdfsdfa
       </Paragraph>
   </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

and the code:

```
bool RtbTapHandled = false;

private void Hyperlink_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hyperlink");
    RtbTapHandled = true;
}

private void RichTextBox_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    if (RtbTapHandled)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    RtbTapHandled = false;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RTB_Tap");
}

private void ContentPanel_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Content_Tap");
}
```

In this case if you click on the `RichTextBox` you'll get callbacks from both `RichTextBox_Tap_1` and `ContentPanel_Tap_1`, but if you click on the `Hyperlink` you'll get `Hyperlink_Click_1` and `RichTextBox_Tap_1` though it'll be handled at that level and stopped.

Comment: Yup, that's pretty neat. Thanks!